# linear operator $A$ and $B$ commute

Tags: linear-algebra

This Is exercise problem from my lecturer

Prove that if the linier operators $A$ and $B$ commute (i.e., if $AB=BA$), then every eigen space of the operator $A$ is invariant subspace of the operator B.

Comment: what's invariant subspace mean?

Comment: $B(V)\subset V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $A,B\colon X \to X$. A subspace $U \subseteq X$ is $B$-invariant or an invariant subspace of $B$ if $Bu \in U$ for all $u \in U$, that is $B(U) \subseteq U$. Now let $U$ be an eigenspace of $A$, that is $Au = \lambda u$ for all $u\in U$. Let $u \in U$, if $\lambda \ne 0$, then $Bu = \frac 1\lambda BAu = \cdots$ (use $AB = BA$) if $\lambda =0 $ then $Au = 0$, hence $ABu = BAu = \cdots$.